# Change structure of JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i am a beginner in javascript and i have a litle problem.

**I have this :**

```
[
  {
    "date": "2014-04-23 00:00:00",
    "volumetrie": "22458"
  },
  {
    "date": "2014-05-02 00:00:00",
    "volumetrie": "30585"
  },
  {
    "date": "2014-03-27 00:00:00",
    "volumetrie": "49536"
  }
]
```

**And i would like this :**

```
[
  {
    "x": "2014-04-23T22:00:00.000Z",
    "y": 22458
  },
  {
    "x": "2014-05-02T22:00:00.000Z",
    "y": 30585
  },
  {
    "x": "2014-03-27T22:00:00.000Z",
    "y": 49536
  }
]
```

Do you have any ideas ?
Thank you very much for you future answer ;)

Comment: Aren't dates in the resulting array required to be ISO strings ?

Comment: Although the question is closed now as a duplicate if you are looking for an exact answer then use  new Date(<date string here>).toISOString() to convert the date into your required format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var arr = [
  {
    "date": "2014-04-23 00:00:00",
    "volumetrie": "22458"
  },
  {
    "date": "2014-05-02 00:00:00",
    "volumetrie": "30585"
  },
  {
    "date": "2014-03-27 00:00:00",
    "volumetrie": "49536"
  }
];

var newArr = arr.map(function(item){
   return {x: item.date, y: item.volumetrie};
});
```

Comment: Keep an eye on the browser compatibility for this one - IE8 is apparently not supported - you'd have to write your own map or use something like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) if you need to support it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by

```
var origArr = [{"date": "2014-04-23 00:00:00","volumetrie": "22458"},{"date": "2014-05-02 00:00:00","volumetrie": "30585"},{"date": "2014-03-27 00:00:00","volumetrie": "49536"}];
```

`forEach` to loop through the elements of the array and create your own

```
var modifArr = [];

origArr.forEach(function(elem){
    modifArr.push({ x : (new Date(elem.date)).toISOString(), y : elem.volumetrie })
});

console.log(modifArr); // the array that you need
```

Or `map`

```
var modifArr = origArr.map(function(elem){
    return { x : (new Date(elem.date)).toISOString(), y : elem.volumetrie }
});

console.log( modifArr );
```

or jQuery's `each`

```
var modifArr = [];

$(origArr).each(function(index, elem){
    modifArr.push({ x : (new Date(elem.date)).toISOString(), y : elem.volumetrie })
});

console.log( modifArr );
```

Comment: Please don't use jQuery for things like this.

Comment: @pablochan It looks like `forEach` is not available in IE8, so jQuery would be a reasonable alternative if you need to support that. Still the biggest reason to use jQuery for me is to handle old browsers - a reasonable percentage of users are still on IE8.

Comment: @JoeEnos The snarky answer would be "Please don't support IE8", but I won't say that. I will concede that if you already have jQuery for other things, using it is not that bad.

Comment: @pablochan Yep, I try to tell my boss to not support IE8 all the time. Doesn't work :)

Comment: @KamranAhmed - As the question is closed as duplicate you may please edit your answer to use (new Date(item.date)).toISOString() so that the question is accurately answered. It might help the user who asked this completely.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map()`. Example:

```
var test = [
    {
        "date": "2014-04-23 00:00:00",
        "volumetrie": "22458"
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-05-02 00:00:00",
        "volumetrie": "30585"
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-03-27 00:00:00",
        "volumetrie": "49536"
    }
];
var newArr = test.map(function(key){
    return {x: key.date, y: key.volumetrie};
});
console.log(newArr);
```